# Aggregate and calculate median of arrayfield in django queryset

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm wondering if this is possible in a more efficient way.
I have a dataset in PostGRESQL that is structured like this:

```
Year, Sitename, Array (length = 4500)
```

For example:

```
1982, DANC, array([2,3,4,5,6,7,...])  
1982, ANCH, array([5,6,4,3,5,7,...])  
1983, DANC, array([3,3,4,6,3,6,...])  
1983, ANCH, array([8,8,5,4,3,2,...])
```

What I want to do is add up the arrays (across rows) by years

```
E.G.,   
1982  1982  1982  
DANC  ANCH  TOT  
2     5     7  
3     6     9  
4     4     8  
5     3     8  
6     5     11  
7     7     14  
...   ...   ...
```

My Django model looks like this:

```
class Abundance(models.Model):
    abundance_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    site = models.ForeignKey('Site')
    season = models.SmallIntegerField()        
    samples = ArrayField(models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=3, max_digits=30))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.site
```

The following code in my Views.py works:

```
import numpy as np
import bottleneck as bn
...


def testview(request):

    s = ["ACUN","BRDM"]
    quants = []
    medians = [] 
    for yr in range(1982,2015):                              
        X = Abundance.objects.values_list('samples').filter(site__site_id__in = s).filter(season = yr)
        h = np.matrix(np.array(X,dtype=float))    
        i = h.sum(axis=0)    
        m = bn.median(i)    
        up = np.percentile(i,95)
        down = np.percentile(i,5)
        qlist = [yr, round(down,3), round(up,3)]
        mlist = [yr, round(m,3)]
        quants.append(qlist)
        medians.append(mlist)

    return JsonResponse({'quants':quants, 'medians':medians})
```

However, the above code is very slow - especially when drawing many sites. I have tried playing with .aggregate() but I've not found a good solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use some of the `.aggregate()` on there to push the load down to Postgres, but I think one of the bigger problems with speed here is the Decimal field. It's the highest precision, but it's also one of the more expensive types for Python to move in and out of.

That said, I'm not sure if there's a quick way to get the percentiles out from the DB call but the sums and medians you can easily push down to the DB via the Django ORM. For the others (percentiles, etc.) you can probably push them down as well but you'll be delving into custom aggregates for django (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#creating-your-own-aggregate-functions), which if you're going to go that far it might be worth checking out something like aldjemy (https://github.com/Deepwalker/aldjemy/) and convert the entire query over to SQLAlchemy so you have maximum control over it.